# TableDestination:="Sheet2!R1C1"

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Macro1()

    Sheet2.Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-69
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A1").Select
    Dim Endrow&
    Endrow = Sheet3.Range("H1").End(xlDown).Row
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        Sheet3.Name & "!R1C8:R" & Endrow & "C21", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable _
        **TableDestination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1)**, TableName:= _
        "PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6
```

I tried to make this Pivot Tables Macro insert into Sheet2!R1C1 (which is an existing worksheet), instead of creating a new worksheet. However, I receive Run-time error

> 5: Invalid Procedure call or argument.

I have tried to following methods

```
TableDestination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1)
TableDestination:="Sheet2!R1C1"
TableDestination:=Sheet2.name & "!R1C1"
```

but all failed. How can I make this right?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works on the assumption that there are worksheets with the Code Name (not names!) of Sheet2 and Sheet3. Could it be that you're referring to the sheet's object name which possibly has changed? This works … if you have a Sheet2 and Sheet3

```
Sub Macro1()
    Sheet2.Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-69
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A1").Select
    Dim Endrow&
    Endrow = Sheet3.Range("H1").End(xlDown).Row
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        Sheet3.Name & "!R1C8:R" & Endrow & "C21", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1), TableName:= _
        "PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6
End Sub
```

Perhaps check that when you refer to Sheet2 and Sheet3 that they still exists.

```
Public Sub ListSheetNames()
    Dim vSheet As Worksheet
    For Each vSheet In Worksheets
        Debug.Print "Code Name/Sheet Name: " & vSheet.CodeName & "  / " & vSheet.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

Maybe change Sheet2 reference to the below … and similarly for Sheet3

```
sheets("Sheet2")
```

Comment: Hi Techno, I used VBA names, not worksheet names. For example, Sheet1 is always Sheet1 in VBA, but its worksheet name can be anything. This is why I want to use VBA name in this case, since worksheet name will change monthly, but Sheet2 is called Sheet2 in VBA no matter what. Thanks.

Comment: OK. If its not that, then I can't see what the issue is. I ran the code above without error. Hope you find the issue.